# Probability outputs for SVM(SMO) in WEKA

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, svm, weka

I have two input classes, 0 and 5. I have trained my classifier using these two labels on the training data.

While testing, before being clearly assigned to every class, I wish to obtain the probabilities that the SVM calculates for every instance.

When I use `classifier.distributionForInstance()`, I am only obtaining 0.000 and  1.000 values pertaining to every instance.
Eg. [0 :  1.000][5 :  0.000][0 :  1.000][5 :  0.000]

While creating the relation for the arff file, I defined the label attribute as follows `bw.write("@attribute label {0,5}");` , where bw is a BufferedWriter object.

What should be the procedure for obtaining the intermediate probability values of the SVM?

Comment: It looks, that you didn't use any cross-validation scheme to select your SVM-parameters, which results in very bad predictions (only containing a very small set of different values). This would mean, that ```distributionForInstance``` only transforms the already bad prediction-values.

Comment: Cross-validation while prediction doesn't make any sense?

I have performed a 2-fold cross validation, and the results for the binary classification that I'm getting are pretty good. My query is to obtain the intermediate probabilities so that I can maybe use those predictions to divide instance into intermediate classes as well. 

I haven't used a multiclass classifier directly because it happens to reduce my system's overall accuracy.

Comment: The concept of intermediate-classes does not sound good (in theory). Predicting probabilities with SVMs is usually quite bad (because it's out of concept; normally done with Platt-scaling & and maybe some extra isotonic-regression). Normally, you could only do ranking. I'm not sure what Weka does internally. My assumption/idea of what's going wrong was mostly based on the numbers you presented in your other SO-question. These prediction-numbers (only 3 unique values) look suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, I think here 0.000 and 1.000 are intermediate probabilities only as you are creating a 2-way classifier.

If instead of 2-way classifier, you try to create a 3-way classifier you will see cases like - " 3.3333, 6.6666 and 0.000" or "3.3333, 3.3333 and 3.3333" and so on....

I hope this helps.